# is there a holomorphic function defined on a neigborhood of $0$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{1+n}$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Can there be a holomorphic function $f$ defined in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ with the property $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{1+n}$?

I'm not sure, if I've solved this correctly. I want to use the identity theorem. It is $(\frac{1}{n})\subseteq U$ and $U$ contains $0$. Furthermore $f$ is holomorphic in $U$ and $f(\frac{1}{n})\to 0$. The identity theorem states that then $f$ has to be zero in $U$, i.e. there is no holomorphic function defined on a neigborhood of $0$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{1}{1+n}$. Is it correct?

What about $g(\frac{1}{n})=(-1)^n$?

Comment: Wouldn't your approach also "prove" that the only $f$ such that $f(1/n)=1/n$ for every positive integer $n$ is $f=0$? 'Cause then we may have a problem (Houston). What is the exact statement of this "identity theorem" you try to use, already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

$$
f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1},
$$
is defined as a holomorphic function in in $\mathbb D(0,1)$, and
$$
f\Big(\frac{1}{n}\Big)=\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$